# Updating values in Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

```
func updateFirebase(){
    myFun = thisIsMyFunTextView.text
    IAm = iAmTextView.text
    var profileKey = String()
    profileRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "uid").queryEqual(toValue: userID).observe(.value, with:{
        snapshot in
            for item in snapshot.children {
                guard let data = item as? FIRDataSnapshot else { continue }
                guard let dict = data.value as? [String: Any] else { continue }
                guard let profileKey = dict["profileKey"] else { continue }
                self.profileRef.child(profileKey as! String).child("bodyOfIAM").setValue(IAm)
                self.profileRef.child(profileKey as! String).child("bodyOfThisIsMyFun").setValue(myFun)
        }
    })
}
@IBAction func backButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    updateFirebase()
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 4, execute: {
        self.dismiss(animated: true)
    })
}
```

myFun and IAm are successfully defined by the changes to the textviews by the user. I can't extract the childByAutoID value without triggering this for in loop that does not end once called, continuing even as a new view controller is presented. The "bodyOfThisIsMyFun" vacillates between the old value and the new value during this loop while the "bodyOfIAM" gets correctly redefined right away and stays that way like it should. How do I get the extracted new values to replace the old values here?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add this line of code at the end of the for...in statement:
self.profileRef.removeAllObservers()